# Rolling 30 day uniques in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose you have a table of the form:

```
create table user_activity (
    user_id int not null, 
    activity_date timestamp not null, 
    ...);
```

It's easy enough to select the number of unique user_id's in the past 30 days.

```
select count(distinct user_id) from user_activity where activity_date > now() - interval 30 day;
```

But how can you select the number of unique user_ids in the prior 30 days for each of the past 30 days? E.g. uniques for 0-30 days ago, 1-31 days ago, 2-32 days ago and so on to 30-60 days ago.

The database engine is mysql if it matters

Comment: Do you want these counts as separate rows? I would think that would be better than 30+ columns, but wanted to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a sub query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `activity_date` as `day`, (
SELECT count(DISTINCT `user_id`) FROM `user_activity` WHERE `activity_date` = `day`
) as `num_uniques`
FROM `user_activity` 
WHERE `activity_date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 day;
```

This should give you the number of unique users for each day.  However, I haven't tested this since I don't have the DB to work with.

Comment: How can I get a sum of these ? I mean I need to get the SUM of the counts for 30 days depending upon the date. That is for today it has to be the sum of today-30days, for yesterday it has to be yesterday-30 days and so on

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this in MySQL, but hopefully the syntax is right. If not, maybe it will point you in the right direction. First, I often employ a Numbers table. It can be a physical table simply made up of numbers or it can be a generated/virtual/temporary table.

```
SELECT
    N.number,
    COUNT(DISTINCT UA.user_id)
FROM
    Numbers N
INNER JOIN User_Activity UA ON
    UA.activity_date >  NOW() - INTERVAL 30 + N.number DAY AND
    UA.activity_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL N.number DAY
WHERE
    N.number BETWEEN 0 AND 30
GROUP BY
    N.number
```

I'm not familiar with the whole INTERVAL syntax, so if I got that wrong, please let me know and I'll try to correct it.

Comment: I think you need a group by in there

Answer (score 0):

If you get the days number for todays date and mod it by 30 you get the offset of the current day.  Then you add that to each number for a date and divide the result by 30, this gives you the group of days.  Then group your results by this number.  So in code something like this:

```
 select count(distinct user_id), (to_days(activity_date)+(to_days(now()) % 30)) / 30 as period
 from user_activity
 group by (to_days(activity_date)+(to_days(now()) % 30)) / 30
```

I will leave calculating the reverse numbering of period up to you (hint: take the period number for the current date as "max" and subtract period above and add 1.)

Comment: doesn't seem right. if I manually plug in select count(distinct user_id) for $date and $date-30 for values of $date the resulting numbers aren't similar

Comment: if you calculate to_days(date) / 30, a day 30 days prior will be off by at most one.  (You might have to floor() it.)

Comment: $date = some arbitrary date in the range, i.e. '2011-05-25', '2011-05-24' etc

Comment: it's off by more than one day. For instance, this returns a value of 2708 for yesterday, but if I plug in `select count(distinct user_id) ... where activity_date between '2011-05-25' - interval 30 day and '2011-05-25'` I get a count of 6688

Comment: are you using to_days(xxx) like I suggest?

Comment: @ʞɔıu - also I was not suggesting the interval stuff was this a comment for @tom answer?